# How to fake generation of ipv6 traffic in linux?

Tags: c, ddos, contiki, iot

I made my prog for ddos attack detection in contiki. Now I want to check whether it is working or not. For that I want to generate fake IPv6 traffic in my application.

I use tools like ping6 inbuilt utility, but it just pings from a single IP. I want to test from different IPs.

Is there any tools for fake IPv6 packet creation or ICMPVv6 generation so I can generate IPv6 traffic and can test my program?

So i just want to know if it is possible through some utility program to generate traffic, analyze it, and generate a result?

Comment: Thanks but i am able to do it in ipv4 manner but in ipv6 i dont know how to do ? any idea

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Scapy](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/). It's a free utility that provides an easy way to construct packets and get their replies. It's general-purpose, and suitable for many purposes including forging packets.